# How to change calender entries in one tenant using App registered another tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform

We are currently building an headleass application (without front end). This app has to be run as deamon  and need to update calander entries of user in different tenant.

We have our seperate Azure subscription where we have created a VM and hosting app. we have different Azure AD tenant thatn the target tenant. I was thinking of registrating the app in our tenant as multi-tenant app. But then I am not sure how it will authorise to change resurces in another tenant.

Or it is must for app to be registered in target tenant?

One of the most important thing is we dont want interactive admin consent flow, as we want everything to be an automatic process. None of the document explains the significance of tenant ID in authentication flow. Anybody knows anything ?

Comment: You only need to create it as a multi-tenant application.

Comment: @CarlZhao, and  admin of another tenant is not required to do anything ?

Comment: Some operations are needed, and I will post the answer with a detailed explanation.

Comment: Hi，  Has your problem been solved?

Comment: @CarlZhao , We have asked admin to give us the permission and thus we are not able to test if this is working . but most probabaly this is the solution. I will definatly mark it it as the solution.

Comment: Okay, looking forward to your results :)

Comment: Getting following error in one of the tenant :
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
        "message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-04-27T17:37:33",
            "request-id": "60e19191-1b10-41ab-9dbb-6f453e5e5d0f",
            "client-request-id": "60e19191-1b10-41ab-9dbb-6f453e5e5d0f"
        }
    }
}

Comment: @CarlZhao, It worked. Admin missed permissions in one of the tenant. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create a multi-tenant application in the original tenant, and then grant the application the `Calendars.ReadWrite` **application permission**.

Next, run admin consent url in the browser, and then you need to log in with another tenant's administrator account and consent. The multi-tenant application will then be added to the target tenant as an **enterprise application**.  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}`.

[image]

At the same time, the application will have the `Calendars.ReadWrite` **application permission** in the target tenant. Finally, you only need to use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to obtain the token and then call the [Update calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) api to change the calendar entry of another tenant.